# No consigo pasar datos JTextField a mis variables

Tags: java, jframe, jtextfield

He creado un JFrame con Swing en Java. En él recojo los campos de (Nombre de tipo String), (PV, PA y Flujo de tipo entero). Intento que estos datos se asignen a las variables en mi programa para construir los distintos objetos que luego se imprimirán en un archivo .txt.
He creado en la clase VentanaInformes que extiende de JFrame los metodos getFlujoTxt(), getPaText(), getNombreTxt() y getPvTxt(), que indican en varios foros y retornan el getTxt() del JTextField correspondiente pero aún con esas no consigo que haga nada.

```
public String getNombretxt() {
    return nombretxt.getText();
}


public String getFlujotxt() {
    return flujotxt.getText();
}


public String getPvtxt() {
    return pvtext.getText();
}



public String getPatxt() {
    return patxt.getText();
}

//metodo para construir paciente 
public Paciente crearPacienteFav(String nombre) {
    VentanaInformes obj=new VentanaInformes();
    nombre=obj.getNombretxt();
    AccesoVascular fistula=new Fistula();
    fistula.getNombre();
    int flujo=Integer.parseInt(obj.getFlujotxt());
    fistula.setFlujo(flujo);
    int pa=Integer.parseInt(obj.getPatxt());
    fistula.setPa(pa);
    int pv=Integer.parseInt(obj.getPvtext());
    fistula.setPv(pv);
    
    Paciente paciente= new Paciente(nombre,fistula);
    
    return paciente;
}
```

El botón que inicia la acción esta programado de la siguiente manera:

```
public void ejecutarBoton() {
    VentanaInformes obj= new VentanaInformes();
    Paciente paciente = null;
    IAccesoInformes informe = new AccesoInformesImp();
    String nombre=obj.getNombretxt();
    
    informe.iniciarInforme();

    
    paciente= informe.crearPacienteFav(nombre);
    

    informe.agregarPaciente(IAccesoInformes.NOMBRE_RECURSO, paciente);
    
}
```

El metodo iniciarInforme() se ejecuta y se crea el archivo.txt correctamente, pero a partir de ahi nada. No se crean los objetos de tipo paciente y por tanto no se agregan al archivo.
Previamente lo he hecho sin JFrame pasando los datos por consola y funcionaba correctamente. No se que modificar, creo que he toqueteado tantas cosas que se me ha ido de las manos.

La salida por consola que da es:

```
archivo borrado
se ha creado el archivo
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:67)
at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:678)
at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:786)
at accesoDatos.AccesoDatosImp.crearPacienteFav(AccesoDatosImp.java:89)
at negocio.AccesoInformesImp.crearPacienteFav(AccesoInformesImp.java:48)
at negocio.AccesoInformesImp.ejecutarBoton(AccesoInformesImp.java:65)
at gui.VentanaInformes$2.actionPerformed(VentanaInformes.java:67)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1972)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2313)
at 
java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.
mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:279)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6626)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3389)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6391)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2266)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5001)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2324)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4833)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4948)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4575)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4516)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2310)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2780)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4833)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:773)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:722)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:716)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege
(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.
doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:97)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:746)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:744)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege
(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:743)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters
(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy
(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

Comment: El mensaje de error es claro: *`Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""`* significa que estás intentando convertir a número una cadena vacía (`""`). En tu código debes controlar que antes de pasar a convertir valores numéricos ese contenido no esté vacío, y también que sea numérico. Hay varias formas de hacer eso. Conviene que ese tipo de conversiones vaya dentro de un bloque `try ... catch`, para capturar cualquier Exception y tu código no se rompa.

Comment: @A.Cedano muchas gracias. No se porqué lo detecta vacío, si introduzco los valores. Aun así creo que me vale como eslabón para seguir intentando. Un saludo

Comment: Dado que no se ve más contexto, poco puedo decirte. Pero depurando el código, poniendo por ejemplo puntos de interrupción, podrás verificar el estado de las cosas y ver por qué llega sin datos.

Comment: @A.Cedrano gracias, en ello estoy. He conseguido que reconozca el texto y ya funciona. Me falta averiguar por que me inicializa en 0 las variables enteras y ando haciendo malabares con el nivel que tengo actualmente. Creo que con un debug no tardaré en sacarlo.

Comment: Sí, te recomiendo que aprendas a hacer debug, si no lo sabes. Puedes poner puntos de interrupción y examinar qué valor tiene cada objeto en ese punto. Así, si hay una variable problemática, puedes examinarla incluso en varios puntos (a veces una variable sufre cambios en el recorrido del código por ejemplo). Si aprendes a hacer debug ganarás muchísimo tiempo desarrollando el código porque no irás a ciegas tanteando dónde está el problema.

Comment: Lo conseguí!!!! Al final con debug y cambiando variables de sitio ha funcionado. Resulta que los métodos que tenia implementados en otros paquetes no reconocían los datos que intentaba pasar de los JTextField a traves de objetos. Finalmente he optado por obtener las variables dentro del metodo **public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)** del propio boton que ejecuta el proceso, y a partir de ahi, he pasado estas variables como argumentos a mis métodos. Los he tenido que adaptar para ello en las Interfaces y de más clases que implementan pero ya funciona. Mil gracias